# Why var keyword is used here?

Tags: javascript, var, let

Here in the below function, we are converting a data url to blob.

Actually I am writing a component that can crop an image...if I use const..then the screen freezes ... and nothing happens...only after using var it seems to be working.

```
const dataURLtoBlob = (dataurl) => {
  var arr = dataurl.split(",");
  var mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1];
  var bstr = atob(arr[1]);
  var n = bstr.length;
  var u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
  n--;

  while (n) {
    u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
  }
  return new Blob([u8arr], { type: mime });
};
```

Why `var` is used here? Is it because `var` can be reassigned and modified?

Comment: No good reason. Maybe just someone who copied and pasted from existing code that used `var`, or someone who doesn't understand the benefits of `const`, or doesn't have a consistent code style. Better to use `const` wherever possible, and `let` when you must reassign, and `var` never.

Comment: var is `the keyword that tells JavaScript you're declaring a variable.`

Comment: `while (n)` is either a noop or an infinite loop. The code doesn't make any sense.

Comment: It should work with `let` and `const` as well! Did you try it with them?

Comment: I think one of the n's in the while loop needs the ```--``` suffix - otherwise as @VLAZ says, the code will infinite loop or skip

Answer (score 0):

In javascript there are 3 ways to declare a variable, var, let, const.

var is global scoped, which means it can be read on the whole function if you declare it inside it, so even if you declared a variable inside the while you wrote you could read it outside it.

let is block scoped, which means it can only be read from the block you declared it in. So if you declared a variable on the while you wrote you could only read it inside the while block.

And const is just like let but it can't be reassigned.

In your case all your variables are declared on the same block and are never reassigned, so let, var and const would work the same way. The most correct way to declare them would be const though, as they are never reassigned, but all would work.

Here's more info: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-var-let-and-const-keywords-in-javascript/

Comment: note that ```u8arr``` might look like it's being modified, but it is not. It could be ```const``` as it is never modified to point to a different array. ie it always points to the same array. It's just the contents of that array that's modified.